# Need to validate file inputs in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, express, mongoose

I m using `Node + Express + MongoDB` to develop my application. In my application there are many file uploading forms. The uploading process is done perfecly. But my problem is , currently there is no validation for the file inputs. I need to validate these file inputs , like

> 1. Need to upload only .jpeg, .png files only.
> 2. File size must be less than 1MB.

But dont know how to solve this. I used `mongoose.js'` model schemas to validate strings and numbers. Searched a lot for finding a solution for file validation, but failed. Anyone who knows how to handle this problem, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should use npm module 'mmmagic' to check file type

```
  var mmm = require('mmmagic'),
  Magic = mmm.Magic;

  var magic = new Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE | mmm.MAGIC_MIME_ENCODING);
  // the above flags can also be shortened down to just: mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE
  magic.detectFile('path/to/your/file.jpg', function(err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log(result);//result is an object containig the file type
  });
```

You can check file size using 'fs' node module